# parse json object array by index position

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, object

Im working on parsing a json object array so that if the value = 'y', the list of keys is returned as a comma-seperated list that is a variable that will be returned in html.

I want to reference the key/value pairs by index position because I only want to return the values that are the key/values #13-39.

Any suggestions about the best way to go about this is?

I already have a jquery map function to access some of the properties through (ie, obj.address). But I havent been able to successfully use filter or grep to only select the object properties with certain key names or index positions.

This is what the array looks like:

```
[{"Name": "Name1", "Key1": "Y", "Key2": "Y", "Key3": "N", "Key4": "Y", "Key5": "N"},
{"Name": "Name2", "Key1": "N", "Key2": "Y", "Key3": "Y", "Key4": "N", "Key5": "N"},
{"Name": "Name3", "Key1": "N", "Key2": "Y", "Key3": "Y", "Key4": "Y", "Key5": "Y"}}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which value should be "Y"? You've provided several in your example code. What should be "Y" in order for you to render the data in the manner you express?

Comment: Any of the key's whose value is 'y' should be displayed. So the comma-seperated list would be, ie for the 1st object in the array: "Key1, Key2, Key4"

Comment: What would be the expected output for the given example array? Should it be something like: `Name1: Key1, Key2, Key4; Name2: Key2, Key3; Name3: Key2, Key3, Key4, Key5`?

Comment: Each Name/object is being displayed as a seperate page in jquery mobile. The pages are being created through jQuery's each. So the list of keys will be tied to the Name/object's page and accessible as a variable, ie "keys", that will be formatted & displayed within the each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can figure out some way to do this using jQuery's `$.map`, but personally I just find it easier to think of in a pure JavaScript way. (Note that if your keys aren't actually named `"Key1"`, `"Key2"`, etc. but you want to access the keys by their position in an associative array, this has no reliable cross-browser implementation.):

```
var bar = [
  {"Name": "Name1", "Key1": "Y", "Key2": "Y", "Key3": "N",
                    "Key4": "Y", "Key5": "N"},
  {"Name": "Name2", "Key1": "N", "Key2": "Y", "Key3": "Y",
                    "Key4": "N", "Key5": "N"},
  {"Name": "Name3", "Key1": "N", "Key2": "Y", "Key3": "Y",
                    "Key4": "Y", "Key5": "Y"}
];
var parsed = {}; // this contains the result
var MIN_KEY = 2; // set to 13 for your request
var MAX_KEY = 4; // set to 39 for your request

for (var i = 0, iLen = bar.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  var baz = bar[i];
  var name;
  var temp = [];
  for (var key in baz) {
    var keyNum = parseInt(key.replace("Key", ""));

    // Get the name or add valid key to an array
    if (key === "Name") {
      name = baz[key];
    } else if (baz[key] === "Y" && keyNum >= MIN_KEY && keyNum < MAX_KEY) {
      temp.push(key);
    }
  }

  // Concatenates temp array like "Key1, Key2, Key3"
  parsed[name] = temp.join(", ");
}

console.log(bar);
console.log(parsed);
```

Alternative implementation by counting keys (note that this may not be reliable across browsers):

```
for (var i = 0, iLen = bar.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  var counter = 0;
  var baz = bar[i];
  var name;
  var temp = [];
  for (var key in baz) {
    if (key === "Name") {
      name = baz[key];
    } else if (baz[key] === "Y" && counter >= MIN_KEY && counter < MAX_KEY) {
      temp.push(key);
    }
    counter++;
  }
  parsed[name] = temp.join(", ");
}
```

Comment: Ok - yeah - they're not actually named Key1, Key2 etc. So there is no reliable cross-browser way to access them by index position?

Comment: Not really. [Here's some more info.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316618/do-javascript-arrays-and-objects-have-a-set-order/6316786#6316786) You can use the `for` loop above and use a counter variable (see my edit above), then test against that if you want to, just keep in mind that there's no real standard and things may not work.

Comment: Ok - thanks a lot for that link. I was wondering why it seemed like things kept coming back semi-randomly... now I know. Thanks a lot for yr help.